# Python keyboard library arrow keys problem

Tags: python, keyboard

I was writing a script, which takes a screenshot and decodes specific key presses in the name of the image as seen below.
My problem is that when I press the left keyboard arrow, also the number 4 is pressed.
I can't find anything on google or in the documentation of the keyboard library. I am using Windows and Python 3.6.5

```
(75,)
left arrow pressed
(5, 75)
4 pressed
```

The same thing happens with the down arrow, but with the number 3.

```
(80,)
down arrow pressed
(3, 80)
2 pressed
```

Code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import keyboard  # using module keyboard
import time

keys = [
    "down arrow",
    "up arrow",
    "left arrow",
    "right arrow",
    "w",
    "s",
    "a",
    "d",
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "q",
```

"e",
"f"
]

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        code = []
        try:
            for key in keys:
                if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
                    print(keyboard.key_to_scan_codes(key))
                    print(f"{key} pressed")
                    code.append(1)
                else:
                    code.append(0)
                    
            if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
                print(key + " pressed")
                break
                
            c = "".join(map(str, code))
            snapshot = ImageGrab.grab()
            save_path = str(int(time.time()*1000)) + "-" + c + ".jpg"
            snapshot.save("tmp\\" + save_path)

        except:
            break
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `keyboard` module has simple solutions for instances like these, they use `event-triggered` activation rather than `polling` as is used in your attempt.

example code:

```
import keyboard

def handleLeftKey(e):
    if keyboard.is_pressed("4"):
        print("left arrow was pressed w/ key 4")
        # work your magic

keyboard.on_press_key("left", handleLeftKey)
# self-explanitory: when the left key is pressed down then do something

keyboard.on_release_key("left", handleLeftKey02)
# also self-explanitory: when the left key is released then do something

# don't use both ...on_release & ...on_press or it will be
# triggered twice per key-use (1 up, 1 down)
```

Replace the code below and change it to suit your needs.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        code = []
        try:
            for key in keys:
                if keyboard.is_pressed(key):
                    print(keyboard.key_to_scan_codes(key))
                    print(f"{key} pressed")
                    code.append(1)
                else:
                    code.append(0)
```

Another, more dynamic approach would look like:

```
import keyboard

keys = [
    "down",
    "up",
    "left",
    "right",
    "w",
    "s",
    "a",
    "d",
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "q",
    "e",
    "f"
]

def kbdCallback(e):
    found = False
    for key in keys:
        if key == keyboard.normalize_name(e.name):
            print(f"{key} was pressed")
            found = True
            # work your magic

    if found == True:
        if e.name == "left":
            if keyboard.is_pressed("4"):
                print("4 & left arrow were pressed together!")
                # work your magic

keyboard.on_press(kbdCallback)
# same as keyboard.on_press_key, but it does this for EVERY key
```

Another issue I noticed was that you were using `"left arrow"` when really it was recognized as `"left"` (at least on my system, it may be different on yours, but I assume you want it to work on all systems so it'd be safer using `"left"` instead)

The last method you could use is very statically typed and has no dynamic capabilities, but would work in the case of `"4+left"` or `"left+4"`

```
import keyboard

def left4trigger:
    print("the keys were pressed")

keyboard.add_hotkey("4+left", left4trigger)
# works as 4+left or left+4 (all of the examples do)
```

You seem smart enough to figure out the rest from there.

Comment: Looked like an awesome solution until `ImportError: You must be root to use this library on linux.`

Answer (score 2):

Beware, language may play a role! In my case the 'up' arrow was translated to my local language, you can run the following code to get the key value for your computer:

```
import keyboard    
def onkeypress(event):
    print(event.name)

keyboard.on_press(onkeypress)

#Use ctrl+c to stop
while True:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to deactivate the NumLock button first. I have some issue on pressing Shift key when NumLock is active.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has changed