# Python keyboard module outputs numbers to console when arrow keys pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, output

I am trying to write some code to repetitively clear the console and output a message, whenever I press a key that is added to the console as if I am in an `input()` state, when backspace is pressed the last letter is deleted. I also want to add a "cursor" so that when pressing arrow keys the characters selected move left and right. Everything works as expected except for the arrow keys.

So I scoured the internet for any information on this. I found 1 post, 3 years ago. It is inactive and no answer was given. The post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54973659/python-keyboard-libary-arrow-keys-problem). It is very similar to my question but rather then detecting a press I need to stop random outputs coming out. I am using Python 3 with Windows.

This issue happens exclusively when using the Keyboard module and when detecting arrow presses. If I do not detect the arrow presses this does not happen even when importing the module. My code is as follows:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed("left"): 
  # at this point a "4" is outputted into the console and detected when it wasn't pressed
```

Similarly with up arrow "8" is outputted, with down arrow  a "2" is outputted, and right outputs a "6". This obviously sounds ridiculous but the post I linked above (being the only occurence I have ever read about this) clearly describes this identical problem.

They only wanted to differentiate between a 4 being pressed and a left arrow being pressed. By using `keyboard.hotkey` or `keyboard.on_press_key`, both of which I tried, there were no differences in results.

This should be extremely easy to reproduce, but I would be interested to know if anybody was unable to reproduce this and if it is linked to a specific OS or version of Python. I experienced this same problem a few years ago and quickly gave up on the mini project, now I'm re-experiencing this problem, if there is another way that I can have a function run or detect if an arrow key is currently being pressed down without these numbers being outputted, that would be a solution to this.